# Make png follow mouse while still being able to interact through it

Tags: jquery, mouse, transparent, jquery-events

I'm trying to make a flashlight effect on my site. You should be able to move the flashlight with your mouse, I've made the flashlight by making a black png with a transparent centre follow my mouse. The problem is that i want to be able to interact with stuff underneath the png. The only way I found to do that is by using `"pointer-events: none;"`, but the the png won't follow my mouse.

Is there any way to make my png follow the mouse above everything else but still being able to  click through the png?

This is my code for following the mouse:

```
  $("#back").mousemove(function(e){
  $('.follow').css('top', e.clientY-2000).css('left', e.clientX-2350);
  });
```

This is my code for the image without `pointer-events:none`:

```
<div id="back" style="width:0px;height:0px">

 <id class="follow"><img src="img/flashlight.png"  style="position: absolute; 
 z-index:10;"/></id>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably doing is setting `pointer-events:none` for an object and then trying to capture `mousemove` events on the same object. That won't work — `mousemove` events are also pointer events.

What you need to do is capture the movement of the mouse somewhere else (even in the `<body>` element), and use these events to control your overlay image.

Unfortunately jsfiddle is down at the moment, but this HTML illustrates the solution (using a block of text instead of an image, but you'll get the picture.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<style>
#loupe {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  opacity:0.5;
  font:10px/10px monospace;
  overflow:hidden;
  pointer-events:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Select This Text</h1>
<p>It should be possible, even with the overlay div in the way.</p>
<p>Here's a button for you to click: <button onclick="alert('Hello World :-)')">Say Hello</button></p>
<div id="loupe">####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################</div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('body').mousemove(function(e){$('#loupe').css('left',e.clientX-50).css('top',e.clientY-50);});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```